# Explanation of Android WebView onPageStarted/onPageFinished methods

Tags: android, cordova, webview

What I actually want to get specified, is that at what moments do these methods exactly get called?

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) on WebView class references, that they get called when *a page has finished loading* and when *a page has started loading*. Loading what - loading the request or rendering the html?

I need to get a method to be called exactly when the html has been downloaded enough, that android webview will start displaying elements on the screen and the explanation for these methods in the documentation seem a bit confusing.

Thanks in advance,
ChillY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods are called when the network requests are started and finish. They have no relationship to content being ready to display or render.

Depending on your exact requirements, you could use the PictureListener callback[1] to let you know when the WebView has some content ready. However this may be flaky if you are loading many URLs, as the picture callback is not necessarily fired for the current URL load - you could receive a stale one for an old page during loading of the next page (e.g. imagine an old page was playing an animation while the new page is loading, or something like that).

An alternative that should work quite reliably is to play a short CSS animation in your HTML, and call back to Java via a JavaScript interface[2] when that animation completes. When you get that callback, WebView should be rendering the content.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setPictureListener(android.webkit.WebView.PictureListener)
[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)